# Angular2 and md-checkbox - how to use flexbox to create columns

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material2

I am having a terrible time trying to wrap an md-checkbox in angular2 with flex.  I will have 30+ items and want to have at least three columns.

I want each column to display vertically.  So 3 columns of 10.  What am I doing wrong?  Below I am trying to create 2 cols with each col displaying vertical but instead the checkboxes are horizontal

Here is my html and css...

```
<div  class="flex-container-fx">
            <div  *ngFor="let fx of currency_list;let i=index">

                        <div class="flex-items-default-fx">
                            <div *ngIf="i<5" formArrayName="selected_currency_list">
                                <mat-checkbox [formControlName]="i" (change)="onCurrencyChange(i)">{{fx}}</mat-checkbox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex-items-default-fx-1">
                            <div *ngIf="i>=5" formArrayName="selected_currency_list">
                                    <mat-checkbox [formControlName]="i" (change)="onCurrencyChange(i)">{{fx}}</mat-checkbox>
                            </div>
                        </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.flex-container-inner-fx {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}


.flex-items-default-fx {

  background-color: blue;
}

.flex-items-default-fx-1 {

  background-color: pink;
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://ng-run.com/edit/1NIYCcK4s60BRihD6V2k?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: You need `flex-wrap: wrap` on the container/parent for them to wrap, then give the item/child any width you want, e.g. 33% if to have 3 per row.

Comment: @LGSon your solution worked!  Thanks